# Database for a small java application

Tags: java, sql, database

I am relatively new to programming and in need of help.
I am trying to  design/develop small desktop app for a family hotel.
Do I need a database to write/read from  or there is  another solution  to this problem.

There aren't massive amounts of information to be stored  ,because of the nature of the application. 
What would be a good way to approach the problem ?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Don’t think about the amounts of information but about the reliability required to run a business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite is the go to solution for simple usage

Answer (score 0):

You can read/write your data to files. The files can be simple text, JSON or XML. There are many Java libraries that can interact with files on disc.

Depending on your requirements you can also have an in-memory database - for example [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)